# Optimizing the query with 2 distinct counts in select

Tags: postgresql, optimization

This SQL works perfectly but it is pretty slow for me.
I did all performance improvement in my database. More complex queries works faster. ( Postgresql 10.x )

How can I optimize or make this query faster?

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.message_id) :: DECIMAL / COUNT(DISTINCT b.order_item_id) :: DECIMAL
FROM messages a
INNER JOIN order_items b
  ON a.product_id = b.product_id;


Aggregate  (cost=53169.94..53169.96 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=10281.758..10281.758 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..14266.71 rows=7780646 width=8) (actual time=0.015..4054.449 rows=7811063 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on messages a  (cost=0.00..775.82 rows=15582 width=8) (actual time=0.007..4.527 rows=15582 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using order_items_product_id on order_items b  (cost=0.29..0.73 rows=14 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.174 rows=501 loops=15582)
              Index Cond: (product_id = a.product_id)
Planning time: 0.450 ms
Execution time: 10281.813 ms
```

Comment: What's the schema on both the tables?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Explain analyse added. For other info you asked is there a query tat I can quickly generate what you need to analyse?

Comment: Yes, with psql, paste the result `\d messages` and `\d order_items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a many-to-many relationship between `messages` and `order_items` through `products`, as a product can appear in many order_items and many messages and also a message (or an order_item) can have many products.

This results in the query producing a variation of a `CROSS JOIN`, and thus the need for using `DISTINCT` in the counts and consequently the poor performance.

I'd suggest you try adding composite indexes on both tables, on `(product_id, order_item_id)`, `(product_id, message_id)` and see if they are used.

Another approach would be to rewrite the query so it doesn't use `DISTINCT`:

```
WITH 
  cm AS
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_messages
      FROM messages AS m
      WHERE EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 
              FROM order_items AS o
              WHERE m.product_id = o.product_id
            )
    ),
  co AS
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_order_items
      FROM order_items AS o 
      WHERE EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 
              FROM messages AS m
              WHERE m.product_id = o.product_id
            )
    )
SELECT cm.count_messages :: DECIMAL / co.count_order_items :: DECIMAL
         AS result
FROM cm, co ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely you need the first `DISTINCT` unless message_id is **not** `UNIQUE?

That is to say, these two are the same,

```
COUNT(DISTINCT a.message_id) :: DECIMAL / COUNT(DISTINCT b.order_item_id) :: DECIMAL
```

vs..

```
COUNT(a.message_id) :: DECIMAL / COUNT(DISTINCT b.order_item_id) :: DECIMAL
```

The other `DISTINCT` is a lot more difficult and would require a [loose index scan to speed up.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan).

Comment: message_id and order_item_id are primary keys. Also these 2 give me different results.
Also since this is a joined table message_id and order_item_id may repeat themselves in different column values. So that I need to get distinct.